# Periodically outputting statistics inside a loop

Tags: python

I have a program which runs constantly using [daemon.runner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemon-runner).  It processes data from `stdin` constantly and I use [syslog](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html) for output.

The code looks like:

```
class App():
  lines = 0

  def __init__(self):
    # Config

  def run(self):
    while True:
      with open(PIPE_NAME) as pipe:
        for line in pipe:
          # Do stuff
          self.lines = self.lines + 1

      # Reopen pipe if required (or die if it's unavailable)
```

I'd like to output statistics periodically, for example every 15 minutes.  I could check the time each time a line is processed however there are occasionally large gaps between incoming data items.

What ways are there to regularly output `self.lines` from this example at a fixed interval?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Currently 2.7 but 3.2 might be a possibility (code is deployed to Debian stable) @JonClements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iteration, check to see if 15 minutes has passed since the last time you printed. If so, print, and record the last time printed.

Use a [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) loop to ensure that you check the time at least every print interval (essentially a "read with timeout"):

```
import os
import select
import time

PRINT_INTERVAL = 15*60  # sec

def run():
    with open(PIPE_NAME) as pipe:
        last_print = 0
        while True:
            timeout = PRINT_INTERVAL - (time.time() - last_print)
            r,w,e = select.select([pipe], [], [], timeout)

            if pipe in r:
                # pipe is ready for reading
                handle_pipe(pipe)

            if (time.time() - last_print) > PRINT_INTERVAL:
                last_print = time.time()
                print_statistics()

def handle_pipe(pipe):
    for line in pipe:
       # Do stuff...

def print_statistics():
    print 'Statistics...'
```

Comment: "I could check the time each time a line is processed however there are occasionally large gaps between incoming data items."

Comment: I think this is the solution I knew would exist but hadn't seen before. Will try it tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: This seems to have the opposite problem that it never returns from handle_pipe after the first select().  I will attempt a fix, however if there is a recommended solution I would appreciate it.

Comment: I have "fixed" this by reading one line in handle_pipe then yielding back to another select.  If there is a better way I'd appreciate any info.

Comment: @David I don't know what you've got writing on the other end of the pipe, but it's not inherently line-delineated. I'm thinking you should maybe just `pipe.read()` whatever is there, and process it after calling `.splitlines()` on the data. You may need to "keep" whatever is left until the next go 'round. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Multi-Threading:

```
import threading
import time

class App():
    lines = 0

    def __init__(self):
        # Config

    def run(self):
        myTimer = threading.Thread(target = self.timer)
        myTimer.start()

        while True:
            with open(PIPE_NAME) as pipe:
                for line in pipe:
                    # Do stuff
                    self.lines = self.lines + 1

            # Reopen pipe if required (or die if it's unavailable)

    def timer(self):
        start = time.time()
        while True:
            if time.time() - start > 900: # should be 15 minutes
                break

        print(self.lines)
        timer()
```

> Multithreading is the ability of a program or an operating system to serve more than one user at a time and to **manage multiple simultaneous requests** without the need to have multiple copies of the programs running within the computer.

This solution is fast and does not have to wait on anything, it just does its job and nothing else.  I have tested this out a little, but if there are any problems, just say.  I really hope this helps. :)

Comment: The bolded part of your quote doesn't apply here: this is a pipe, not a TCP listener. Otherwise you're basically just quoting generic information about the module you're using. Personally, I really dislike when people introduce multithreading into programs instead of using `select` or `poll`. It introduces an entire class of potential issues when it's not necessary.

Comment: I have never used (let alone heard of) `select` or `poll`, but I am looking into it right now.

Comment: It's basically a way to wait on a large number of events in a single thread. It's far more efficient to use `epoll` with hundreds of file descriptors than it is to spin up hundreds of threads.